# How to confirm the working of Remote Storage with Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, media-images

I have successfully configured and synced the media files to the Amazon S3 bucket(as mentioned in https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/remote-storage/config-remote-storage-aws-s3.html) but still, the product images are getting loaded from the media cache folder. How to confirm whether Remote storage is successfully installed or not.Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Magento recently added this documentation, https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/storage/remote-storage/cloud-support.html?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

You can check if newly uploaded product images in magento are visible in S3 or not. For me, when I restarted magento then it starts uploading to S3.